# Optimize connection with Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using a script PHP to get all posts from a fan page. The code is this:

```
require_once("../facebook-sdk/src/facebook.php");

$config = array(
    'appId' => '#############',
    'secret' => '###############################',
    'fileUpload' => false
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$facebook->setAccessToken("###################################");

$pageid = "###############";

$pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/feed");

$i = 0;

foreach($pagefeed['data'] as $post) {
    if ($post['type'] == 'video' || $post['type'] == 'link' || $post['type'] == 'photo') {

        // open up an fb-update div
        echo "<div class=\"fb-update\">";

        // check if post type is a link
        if ($post['type'] == 'link') {
            echo '<a href="' . $post['link'] . '" target="_blank"><img class="imagem-feed" src="' . $post["picture"] . '"></a>';
            $interno = "<p>" . $post['message'] . "</p><p><a href=\"" . $post['link'] . "\" target=\"_blank\">" . $post['link'] . "</a></p>";
        }

        // check if post type is a photo
        if ($post['type'] == 'photo') {
            $fotoAlta = $facebook->api("/" . $post["object_id"] . "?fields=source");
            echo '<a href="' . $post['link'] . '" target="_blank"><img class="imagem-feed" src="' . $fotoAlta["source"] . '"></a>';

            //interno
            if (empty($post['story']) === false) {
                $interno = "<p>" . $post['story'] . "</p>";
            } elseif (empty($post['message']) === false) {
                $interno = "<p>" . $post['message'] . "</p>";
            }
            $interno .= "<p><a href=\"" . $post['link'] . "\" target=\"_blank\">Ver no Facebook &rarr;</a></p>";
        }

        // check if post type is a video
        if ($post['type'] == 'video') {
            echo '<iframe class="imagem-feed" width="350" height="263" src="' . str_replace("&autoplay=1","",$post["source"]) . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

            //interno
            if (empty($post['story']) === false) {
                $interno = "<p>" . $post['story'] . "</p>";
            } elseif (empty($post['message']) === false) {
                $interno = "<p>" . $post['message'] . "</p>";
            }
        }

        echo '<div class="cabecalho-fanpage"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Angelameza.arquitetura"><img class="img-perfil-fanpage" width="50" height="50" src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/373040_201176906637605_665931623_q.jpg"><h1>' . $post["from"]["name"] . '</h1><p>' . date("d/m/Y", (strtotime($post['created_time']))) . '</p></a></div>';

        echo $interno;

        echo '<div class="container-interacoes">';
        $totalCurtidas = $facebook->api("/" . $post["id"] . "/likes/?summary=true");
        $titulo = ($totalCurtidas["summary"]["total_count"] == 0 || $totalCurtidas["summary"]["total_count"] > 1) ? $totalCurtidas["summary"]["total_count"] . " pessoas curtiram isso." : "1 pessoa curtiu isso.";
        echo "<span title='$titulo' class='icon-curtidas'>" . $totalCurtidas["summary"]["total_count"] . "</span>";

        $compartilhamentos = (isset($post["shares"]["count"])) ? $post["shares"]["count"] : 0;
        $titulo = ($compartilhamentos == 0 || $compartilhamentos > 1) ? $compartilhamentos . " pessoas compartilharam isso." : "1 pessoa compartilhou isso.";
        echo "<span title='$titulo' class='icon-compartilhamentos'>" . $compartilhamentos . "</span>";

        $totalComentarios = $facebook->api("/" . $post["id"] . "/comments/?summary=true");
        $titulo = ($totalComentarios["summary"]["total_count"] == 0 || $totalComentarios["summary"]["total_count"] > 1) ? $totalComentarios["summary"]["total_count"] . " pessoas comentaram isso." : "1 pessoa comentou isso.";
        echo "<span title='$titulo' class='icon-comentarios'>" . $totalComentarios["summary"]["total_count"] . "</span>";
        echo "</div>";

        echo "<div style='clear:both'></div></div>"; // close fb-update div

        $i++; // add 1 to the counter if our condition for $post['type'] is met
    }
} // end the foreach statement
```

Using this code, the page is very slow (50 seconds to load). I tested any thing for optimize and don't improve. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making calls to graph API inside the for loop, i.e for every post, you are making additional calls. Obviously, this contributes towards your 50 secs. Your best bet is to arrange your code to use batch requests. Here is the documentation for batching calls.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Note: You can make upto 50 calls in one go using a batch request.

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim. I think the path is this, but i can't understand how to use the id of post with other searches before receive the results.

My requirement from api now is:
$queries = array(
  array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => "/" . $pageid . "/feed")
 );
 
 $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');

Comment: you can use your foreach loop to accumulate the post IDs in an array, i.e dont make calls to graph API inside the foreach loop, rather just save the IDs in array. Once you have that array, you can use batch requests.